# How to establish a connection between beaglebone and AWS through websocket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, beagleboneblack

I was planning to send and receive some data from beaglebone to AWS server which runs an EC2 instance of ubuntu.

I have debian Jessy on my beaglebone black.

Can anyone help me on how to go about this? I have no idea about java, i can write a program in C, C++ or Python. It would be more helpful if it is through a websocket protocol. Could you also let me know if there is any API that i need to install on beaglebone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through aws SDK documents first, they will guide you to work out.

Since you knew C++ and Python, here are the documents for you.

[AWS SDK for Python (Boto3)](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/)

[Introducing the AWS SDK for C++](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-the-aws-sdk-for-c/)

Comment: M not sure if i am able to understand Boto3. I will try and learn more about it. Just a simple question, will i be able to send and receive files such as python scripts, text files and images?